# Is there a way to generate abstract syntax tree of a Java source code using Python?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

Currently, I have the JavaLexer.py and JavaParser.py files generated by ANTLR. My goal is this: First, I want to generate Abstract Syntax Trees for Java codes. After generating these ASTs, I want to detect the code similarities between different Java codes using the edit distance metric. For this purpose, I decided to use the ANTLR 4.7.2 with Python 3.6.

Right now, I can parse and get something called compilationUnit() using the JavaParser.py. The code for this is below:

```py
source = open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8")
input_stream = InputStream(source.read())
lexer = JavaLexer(input_stream)
token_stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)

parser = JavaParser(token_stream)
tree = parser.compilationUnit()
print(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))
```

The output of this looks like this:

```
(compilationUnit (typeDeclaration (classOrInterfaceModifier public) (classDeclaration class HelloWorld (classBody { (classBodyDeclaration (modifier (classOrInterfaceModifier public)) (modifier (classOrInterfaceModifier static)) (memberDeclaration (methodDeclaration (typeTypeOrVoid void) main (formalParameters ( (formalParameterList (formalParameter (typeType (classOrInterfaceType String) [ ]) (variableDeclaratorId args))) )) (methodBody (block { (blockStatement (statement (expression (expression (expression (primary System)) . out) . (methodCall println ( (expressionList (expression (primary (literal "HelloWorld")))) ))) ;)) }))))) }))) <EOF>)
```

The question is, with the current setup that I am using, is it possible to parse this output into tree structure?

Comment: You mean you want to get the `tree` object back from just the output of `toStringTree`? Why?

Comment: It can already be implied from sepp2ks comment: the `tree` (returned from `parser.compilationUnit()`) _is_ the parse tree. It has children that can be traversed and all.

Comment: so from your comment @BartKiers I understand that, I should be able to calculate the edit distance of two parse trees that I got from the ```parser.compilationUnit()```.

Comment: Yes, you can...